# php file upload data is not going into mysql

Tags: php

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
//This gets all the other information from the form
  $stnam = $_POST['stName'];
  $stage = $_POST['stAge'];
  $stdob = $_POST['stDob'];
  $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO test (name, age, dob, photo) VALUES ('$stnam', '$stage', '$stdob', 'pic')");

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}

?>
```

I have been trying to upload an image file into sql database using phpmyadmin I used this above code when I executed it the file goes into directory well but the data values are not being inserted into mysql. Can anyone help?

Comment: you for got to place $ before pic

Comment: 1) You didn't check for any errors, make use of [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) function. 2) In the procedural way, [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) takes **at least** 2 arguments, first is the connection handler and second is the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Changes***

**1)** Put **$** before **pic** in insert query.

**2)** And, keep `insert query` inside `if()`. Because, row will get inserted even though file is not moved to desired folder.

**3)** No connection variable is used in `mysqli_query`. It requires 2 arguments. [I assumed `$conn` as connection variable. Replace it according to your connection variable.] For more info, click [mysqli_query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

***Updated Code***

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)){
  mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO test (name, age, dob, photo) VALUES ('$stnam', '$stage', '$stdob', '$pic')");
  echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
} else {
  echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
```

Comment: Wow..it really helped, looks like I did not put the mysqli_query parameters well. Thank you so much for your help Nan Partykar.

Comment: The data is going in to database now.

Comment: Glad. It's Going. If this answer helped you. Then, Don't Forget To Mark This Answer As Correct Answer. As, It will help other user to find it easily. @Krish

Comment: @Krish : Please go through this link. You will get it. Thanks for replying. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work